# Ubuntu 16.04 and Rmarkdown in RStudio 1.0.143 - plots are saved as blank images, how to debug?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I created a big document that properly compiled to LaTeX / PDF some time ago...

But now, when I click on 'Knit' button in Rstudio (to compile it to PDF), during compilation I see following error messages in case of each figure chunk:

```
!!! Error: Ghostscript exited with error code 1!
```

As a result, in created PDF, all plots are empty. They have proper captions, but all images are blank. As I check, all images are empty.

**BUT** when I try to execute following code from the console:

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('myRmarkdown.Rmd')"
```

to change my `.Rmd` file into `.md`, I can see that images are properly generated and saved in 'figure' folder. I don't see any Ghostscript or other errors, so I assume that my .Rmd file is corrrect.

I checked that I have the latest Ghostscript (9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.6) for my machine.

How can I debug generation of PDF from my Rmarkdown file (sorry, but I can't share it) / obtain additional information what is going wrong? I don't know how to fix it / what to do next.

Comment: Knit the default Rmd file proposed by Rstudio and see if the error is still present. Otherwise, this would mean something is wrong in your Rmd file. This has probably more something to do with LateX than with R.

Comment: Since I have my Rmd in git repo, I'm 100% sure that it (my Rmd) wasn't modified since last time I successfully compiled it. Is there any chance to have more logs, more output, debug it step by step?

Comment: Yes but, your LateX installation may have change... In the header, you can add `keep_tex: yes` and it should keep the tex file as well as log files.

Comment: I am able to compile default R markdown documents, but my document is still failing. Correct me if I am wrong, but log file that you mention is related with LaTeX compilation, while I have a problem during previous steps (during R code execution / saving plot). Moreover, I tried to create an AWS virtual machine with R and my document compiles perfectly on this new machine.

Comment: Yes log file is related to Latex compilation. So I imagine this may be due to an old R library, compiled with an old version of ghostscript or so. If your R libraries are not up to date, this may be an explanation. From here, I cannot really help you more. Sorry.